# matplotlib histogram not going lowest to highest

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to graph a set of data as a histogram, and I need the histogram to show the data from lowest to highest, instead its shows them out of order. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

charges = [1.00, 1.03, 1.12, 1.19, 1.22, 1.28, 1.82, 1.89, 2.25, 2.30, 2.31, 2.42, 2.43, 2.53, 2.55, 2.60, 2.67, 2.76, 2.81, 2.83, 2.88, 2.93, 2.94, 2.96, 3.03, 3.13, 3.21, 3.28, 3.39, 3.74, 3.77, 3.88, 4.05, 4.07, 4.26, 4.28, 4.43, 4.46, 4.52, 4.60, 4.96, 5.00, 5.24, 5.55, 5.56, 5.84, 5.90, 7.34, 8.25, 9.73]

plt.hist(charges, len(charges), normed = 0)
plt.ylabel("Charge 10e-19" )
plt.show()
```

How do I force the histogram to print in order from lowest to highest?

Comment: Are you sure you want a histogram, and not a bar chart, i.e. `plt.bar(range(len(charges)), charges)`?

Comment: @wflynny my professor called it a histogram. I just need to show how the data points trend as the values go up.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the output of `hist`: on the `x` axis you have your data (intervals of `charges`), and on the `y` axis you have the occurence of data points in each corresponding interval. Google what a histogram is if you're unfamiliar with the concept, it's a very generic construction.

Comment: @AndrasDeak So what would I need to just graph the data points in succession.

Comment: @Jurad215 `plt.bar(range(len(charges)), charges)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related.  This question revolves around OP's misunderstanding of what a histogram is.

Comment: I think we can't really know if the OP really wanted a bar chart or histogram from the texts of his/her question or comment. He actually said, "shows the data from lowest to highest", and "print in order from lowest to highest". If he needed a bar chart (which is essentially the same thing as the simple `plot`), it sounds a bit unexpected to hear the word "order". I think there is still a possibility that he really needs a histogram but that he just does not know the concept of bin.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the histogram to print in order from lowest to highest as following.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# .. or set the correct path.
# This script was written by norio 2015-12-8.

#import sys, re, os
import numpy as np

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import matplotlib.image as img

mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
mpl.rcParams['lines.markeredgewidth'] = 1.0
mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = (-4,4)
mpl.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 'large'
mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 'large'
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 'large'
mpl.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
mpl.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

#########################################################
# reading or setting the data
#########################################################
charges = [1.00, 1.03, 1.12, 1.19, 1.22, 1.28, 1.82, 1.89, 2.25, 2.30, 2.31, 2.42, 2.43, 2.53, 2.55, 2.60, 2.67, 2.76, 2.81, 2.83, 2.88, 2.93, 2.94, 2.96, 3.03, 3.13, 3.21, 3.28, 3.39, 3.74, 3.77, 3.88, 4.05, 4.07, 4.26, 4.28, 4.43, 4.46, 4.52, 4.60, 4.96, 5.00, 5.24, 5.55, 5.56, 5.84, 5.90, 7.34, 8.25, 9.73]

min_charge_expected=0.0
max_charge_expected=15.0
dcharge=0.50
# .. or perhaps your professor may like the following values
# min_charge_expected=-3.5934806974
# max_charge_expected=12.5481268590347
# dcharge=0.859792487698798

bins_yes_bins_fucking_bins_we_got_it_we_got_the_freedom_yeahhhhh_wooohaaa=np.arange(min_charge_expected, max_charge_expected, dcharge)

############################################
# canvas setting
############################################

f_size   = (8,5)

a1_left   = 0.15
a1_bottom = 0.15
a1_width  = 0.75
a1_height = 0.75

############################################
# plotting
############################################


fig1=plt.figure(figsize=f_size)

ax1 =plt.axes([a1_left, a1_bottom, a1_width, a1_height], axisbg='w')

# plt.hist(charges)
# .. this also works but the following give you the freedom. Yes freedom! What freedom?
plt.hist(charges, bins=bins_yes_bins_fucking_bins_we_got_it_we_got_the_freedom_yeahhhhh_wooohaaa)

plt.minorticks_on()
plt.xlabel('Charge $\upsilon$ (babababaaaan unit)', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Counts $n$', fontsize=18)
ax1.set_xlim([0.0, 10.5])
ax1.set_ylim([0.0, 1.5e1])


plt.savefig('fig_this_is_the_histgram_probably_the_professor_of_Jurad215_really_wanted.eps')
plt.savefig('fig_this_is_the_histgram_probably_the_professor_of_Jurad215_really_wanted.png')
plt.close()
```

If you execute this script, you get two figure files with long names. One is eps and another is png. They will looks like this:

[image]